# Something went wrong with youtube API python file

Tags: python, command-line, youtube, google-api, youtube-api

I'm facing a problem with the youtube API on their website, everything worked well until the final stage where the script they are giving us is not working properly is seems that the synthax they wrote includes some mistakes (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video);
when I run this program python upload_video.py command line gives me several mistakes 
the question is is it normal ? and how can I fix this in order to be able to use the API properly ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Mistakes are probably normal, yes. We'd need to know what they are to fix them. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: They use **Python 2** in their example, maybe you're using **Python 3**? - that may explain the _syntax errors_.